# Rendering a coloured background with transparent foreground in PHP

Tags: php, gd

I am rendering audio waveforms directly from MP3's on the fly as they are uploaded to the server.  My upload script currently saves both the original mp3 and renders the waveform to a png.

Currently I render the background first to a rectangle.  This code produces either a transparent or coloured background dependant upon the value of $background:

I am trying to create a transparent png overlay in PHP.

```
if (!$img) {
        // create original image width based on amount of detail
                // each waveform to be processed with be $height high, but will be condensed
                // and resized later (if specified)
        $img = imagecreatetruecolor($data_size / DETAIL, $height * sizeof($wavs_to_process));

        // fill background of image
        if ($background == "") {
          // transparent background specified
          imagesavealpha($img, true);
          $transparentColor = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 0, 0, 0, 127);
          imagefill($img, 0, 0, $transparentColor);
        } else {
          list($br, $bg, $bb) = html2rgb($background);
          imagefilledrectangle($img, 0, 0, (int) ($data_size / DETAIL), $height * sizeof($wavs_to_process), imagecolorallocate($img, $br, $bg, $bb));
        }
      }
```

I then loop through the data points of a dynamically resampled MP3 and for each point I draw a line onto this background which renders the waveform image.

I use this code to produce the waveform image:

```
 // don't print flat values on the canvas if not necessary
          if (!($v / $height == 0.5 && !$draw_flat))
            // draw the line on the image using the $v value and centering it vertically on the canvas
            imageline(
              $img,
              // x1
              (int) ($data_point / DETAIL),
              // y1: height of the image minus $v as a percentage of the height for the wave amplitude
              $height * $wav - $v,
              // x2
              (int) ($data_point / DETAIL),
              // y2: same as y1, but from the bottom of the image
              $height * $wav - ($height - $v),
              imagecolorallocate($img, $r, $g, $b)
            );      

        } else {
          // skip this one due to lack of detail
          fseek($handle, $ratio + $byte, SEEK_CUR);
        }
      }
```

This works perfectly, however I need to create the waveform as a transparent overlay in order to place it over a div with a CSS gradient.  So, I need to render the background as #ffffff and the actual waveform itself needs to be transparent. In essence I need the transparency inverted on the produced png's.

I have tried using:

```
imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 0, 0, 0, 127)
```

On the waveform rendering portion but always seem to just end up with a coloured rectangle with no visible waveform and I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using an HTML `canvas` element instead of rendering to an image? More a thought than a suggestion.

Comment: Do I understand you right that you first fill all and you then want to "remove" the pixels of the waveform to make that part transparent again?

Comment: Thats correct hakre. I'm not even sure if it is possible and am open to alternative suggestions of course.

Comment: @Treffynnon this application requires that several div's be position above the actual waveform, which if my understanding of the way html canvas elements work, would make this approach troublesome.

Comment: @gordyr: Suggestion added as an answer, should do it. I'd like to see the site when it's done, was interesting already yesterday ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following. [Disable blending mode<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/imagealphablending) for the image:

```
imagealphablending($img, FALSE);
```

This will enable that you can set pixels with alpha information directly. To do so, you need to [allocate the color *with* the alpha<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/imagecolorallocatealpha) set to 100% transparent as well:

```
imagecolorallocatealpha($img ,$r, $g, $b, $alpha = 127);
```

BTW, you can allocate the color once and then re-use it, so you don't need to call the `imagecolorallocatealpha` function that often.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Perfect! I simply missed that I had to disable alpha blending first.  Works beutifully now. Again, a huge thank you hakre.  It's a hugely interesting and ambitious project this.  It's taken me well out of my development/UI engineering comfort zone in several areas and has given me a huge opportunity to learn stuff that I otherwise never would have.  I'll certainly send you a link when it's done.  I'm sure i'll have more questions along the way anyway.  Cheers! :-)